# Can seebeck chips be used to extract Peltier chip waste heat?

Tags: electronics, electrical-engineering, thermoelectricity

I understand that a problem with employing the Peltier effect for the purpose of cooling is that it produces a significant amount of heat on the hot plate. But why don't we use seebeck optimised chips to capture the heat? Surely the more heat generated by the peltier chip, the more heat is recycled back into current by the seebeck chip?

Comment: In order to extract energy from heat one needs a temperature difference. If you try to extract the waste heat, you will inevitably raise the temperature on the cold side of the Peltier element, which will make it less efficient. The problem with Peltier elements is that we have to find material combinations with high electrical conductivity but low thermal conductivity, which, on some level, are linked. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_materials for a discussion and estimates for current and future materials. There is a lot of improvement left.